# Is it possible to examine the current titleformat and titlespacing for a particular title class?

Tags: titlesec, expansion, debugging

I just found out that you can do `\show\titleformat` in interactive mode to see the definition of the titleformat macro. Now I'm wondering how I can see what the title format for `\chapter` (for example) is set to by default.

Is there some fundamental LaTeX debugging technique to show this type of information? Perhaps something akin to `make -np` that would allow me to dump all current definitions?

Comment: try `\makeatletter \show\@chapter \makeatother`

Comment: Interesting. When I do `\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{}{0em}{}` though, it doesn't change the definition of `@chapter`.

Comment: Sorry I misinterpreted the words  `by default`.

Comment: You can add `\tracingmacros=2` before the point where the macros you are interested in are expanded. Then compile the TeX document, and have a look at the .log file. Search for the macros that you are interested in. You will see e.g. a line starting with `\@chapter ->` showing the expansion of this command, as well as the values of the parameters (if the command requires any).